# Deploy a jar to a wildfly server?

Tags: maven, deployment, wildfly

I want to deploy an application packaged in a jar to a wildfly server after maven package phase, and before maven install.

I am using the following plugin in the project pom.xml:

```
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0.Beta1</version>
         <configuration>
              <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
              <port>9990</port>
         </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

how to configure this plugin execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`deploy` goal](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html) of that plugin. It accepts a `filename` parameter which you could use to specify the application archive that you want to deploy.

Binding this goal to the `deploy` phase of Maven will *not* override other goals being invoked in that phase of the Maven lifecycle. They will continue to run.

Comment: Thank you, but will the default maven deploy be overwritten by the one from this plugin, or will they both run?

Comment: Do you mean `mvn deploy`? If so that's a separate goal in a separate namespace so if you bind `wildfly:deploy` to `package` then anytime the package phase is executed the `wildfly:deploy` goal will be executed.